# Prove the existence of domain and range of sets of objects similar to ordered pairs using Axiom Replacement

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am currently studying (on my own) the book "The Foundations of Mathematics" by Kenneth Kunen. As a programmer not much exposed to math, my question may be too trivial. However, please guide me.

I am stuck on the following Exercise I.7.16 on Page 28, which is given as follows (An old draft of this book can be found here https://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/old/m771-10/kunen770.pdf):

> Say we've defined a "pair" $[(x, y)]$ in some way, and assume that we can prove $[(x, y)] = [(x', y')] \to x = x' \land y = y'$. Prove that $\{ x : \exists y [(x, y)] \in R \}$ and $\{ y : \exists x [ [(x, y)] \in R ] \}$ exist for all sets $R$.

I am supposed to use the Axiom of Replacement which is formalised in the book as $\forall x \in A \exists ! y \varphi(x, y) \to \exists B \forall x \in A \exists y \in B \varphi(x, y)$.

I am not sure how to proceed (It looks to me like the question has most of the answer. What am I supposed to prove here?). Please give me a detailed proof that is relatively formal so that I know what exactly I am missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What might have confused you, is that you have to prove that $\{x\mid \exists y([(x,y)]\in R\}$ is a set in the first place. Note that although $\{x\mid \phi(x)\}$ is called *set-builder* notation, not everything in that format has to be a set. An easy example is the universe $V=\{x\mid x=x\}$ and Russell's paradox $\{x\mid x\notin x\}$, neither of which are sets, but proper classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to prove that the class $\{x\mid \exists y([(x,y)]\in R)\}$ is a set using the Axiom of Replacement, so first we look at what the Axiom of Replacement gives us.

The formula $\varphi(x,y)$ in the antecedent of the Axiom of Replacement has a property that is "function-like", in the sense that for every $x\in A$ there is only a single set $y$ which makes $\varphi(x,y)$ true. Therefore in a certain way, we could say that each $x\in A$ is "mapped" to a unique set $y$, namely the set $y$ for which $\varphi(x,y)$ holds.

The consequent of the Axiom of Replacement then says that for some set $A$ there exists a set $B$ that contains exactly all the values to which the sets $x\in A$ are "mapped". In other words, if we have a set $A$, and we define a "function-like" formula $\varphi$, then the image of $A$ under this "function" forms a set.

*Note that I say "function-like", since $\varphi$ is not really a function, but a formula. Functions are usually defined to be sets, and without the Axiom of Replacement, we cannot prove that the class of pairs $(x,y)$ with $x\in A$ such that $\phi(x,y)$ holds is a set.*

---

Now, to prove your statement, define $\varphi(x,y)$ in two ways:

- If $x$ is a "pair" $[(a,b)]$, then we let $\varphi([(a,b)],y)$ be true if and only if $y=a$.
- If $x$ is not a "pair", then we let $\varphi(x,y)$ be true if and only if $x=y$.

It should be easy to see that this $\varphi$ is "function-like" (for this we use that $[(a,b)]=[(a',b')]$ if and only if $a=a'$ and $b=b'$). The thing you then have to show is that if we take $A=R$ in the Axiom of Replacement, then $B$ gives us the required set, assuming that $R$ consists solely of sets that are "pairs".

If $R$ does also contain sets that are not pairs, first make the set $R'=\{x\in R\mid \exists a,b(x=[(a,b)])\}$ using the Axiom of Comprehension / Separation, and then use the Axiom of Replacement on $R'$ instead.